# read XML from and to file while preserving format

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, format

I use this perl code to read XML from a file, and then write to another file (my full script has code to add attributes):

```
#!usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use XML::DOM;
use XML::Simple;

my $num_args = $#ARGV + 1;

if ($num_args != 2) {
  print "\nUsage: ModifyXML.pl inputXML outputXML\n";
  exit;
}

my $inputPath = $ARGV[0];
my $outputPath = $ARGV[1];

open(inputXML, "$inputPath") || die "Cannot open $inputPath \n";

my $parser = XML::DOM::Parser->new();
my $data = $parser->parsefile($inputPath) || die "Error parsing XML File";

open my $fh, '>:utf8', "$outputPath" or die "Can't open $outputPath for writing: $!\n";
$data->printToFileHandle($fh);

close(inputXML);
```

however this doesn't preserve characters like line breaks.  For example, this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test>
    <Notification Content="test1     testx &#xD;&#xA;test2&#xD;&#xA;test3&#xD;&#xA;" Type="Test1234">
    </Notification>
</Test>
```

becomes this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test>
    <Notification Content="test1     testx 

test2

test3

" Type="Test1234">
    </Notification>
</Test>
```

I suspect I'm not writing to file properly.

Comment: When I think "preserving line breaks" this isn't at all what comes to mind.  Here you're looking to preserve *encodings* that coincidentally represent CR/LF characters.

Comment: It looks like XML::DOM sets a default handler to expand everything (see DOM.pm lines 2054-58).  Have you tried fiddling with that to get the noexpand behavior you want?

Comment: that part of XML::DOM doesn't seem to quite work right - thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod), for example. The main modules that get involved are [XML::LibXML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0128/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod) and [XML::LibXML::DOM](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0128/lib/XML/LibXML/DOM.pod) (along with others). The returned object is generally [XML::LibXML::Document](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0128/lib/XML/LibXML/Document.pod)

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;

use XML::LibXML;

my $inputPath  = 'with_encodings.xml';
my $outputPath = 'keep_encodings.xml';

my $reader = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $reader->load_xml(location => $inputPath, no_blanks => 1); 

print $doc->toString();

my $state = $doc->toFile($outputPath);
```

We don't have to first create an object but can directly say `XML::LibXML->load_xml`. I do it as an example since this way one can then use methods on `$reader` to set up encodings (for example), before parsing but outside of the constructor.

This module is also far more convenient for processing.

The [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.49/Twig.pm) should also leave encodings, and is also far better for processing.

Answer (score -1):

FYI, I was able to do this by switching to different XML parser.  Now using XML::LibXML.

Syntax is similar, except it's 'parse_file' instead of 'parsefile', and instead of 'printToFileHandle' you use 'toFile' with a filename.

Comment: You can comment this on answer by zdim or edit the answer to improve.

Comment: As you can tell by the 'answered' timestamp, this answer predates zdim's answer.

Comment: Ohh, my apologies. (If wondering, it's not my downvote, just mentioning in case).